# Proof about a given plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So, I've been scratchin my head about this one.

Consider the function $f(x,y,z)=x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}+z^{2/3}$. Let $\pi$ be a plane tangent to the level surface $c$ of the function $f$, where $C$ is a positive constant. Prove that the sum of the coordinates $x,y,z$ of the intersection points of the plane $\pi$ with the coordiantes axes is constant.

Here is what I've done:

So, as I understand it, I have to prove that for any given plane tangent to that surface. 
I use the gradient vector, evaluated at an arbitrary point $x_0,y_0,z_0$ which would be the normal vector for any plane tangent to the surface.

With the vector and the point I write the plane as:
$$x_0^{-1/3}x+y_0^{-1/3}y+z_0^{-1/3}z=D$$
Evaluating the plane at the point $x_0,y_0,z_0$ yields:
$$x_0^{2/3}+y_0^{2/3}+z_0^{2/3}=D$$
Wwhich happens to be the constant $C$ of the level surface. So at this point I can write the plane as:
$$\pi:x_0^{-1/3}x+y_0^{-1/3}y+z_0^{-1/3}z=C$$
Let $x_1,y_1,z_1$ be the intersections with the coordinates axes, evaluating I get:
$$x_1=Cx_0^{1/3};  y_1=Cy_0^{1/3};z_1=Cz_0^{1/3}$$
So the sum of the squares would be:
$$x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2=C^2x_0^{2/3}+C^2y_0^{2/3}+C^2x_0^{2/3}\\
x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2=C^2(x_0^{2/3}+y_0^{2/3}+z_0^{2/3})\\
x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2=C^3$$
Would this be correct?

Comment: I think you need to show that $\;x_1+y_1+z_1\;$ is a constant...